# XDispatch Visual Studio GCD

Tags: c++

I am trying to use GCD in Visual Studio.

Here is the entire installation procedure as defined by the website for xdispatch.

> Extract the archive and copy it to some place on the disk. The
>   provided archives contain three directories:
>
> include - Location of the header files 
>   lib - Location of the lib files
>   you will have to link against
>   bin - Location of the dll files.
>
> To use xdispatch, make sure the three directories listed above are
>   listed in the INCLUDE, LIB and PATH (for the bin directory)
>   environment variables. When using Visual Studio you might also want to
>   change the include and linker directories within your project
>   configuration. Afterwards you can use the libraries by including one
>   of the headers

I know this is basic stuff.

The environmental variables contain path, but not include and lib. They just are not there. I can add a new variable, but these are system variables right?

Is it as simple as creating two new variables... INCLUDE(for include dir) and LIB(for include dir) then add bin to PATH.

Then for Visual Studio. Should it just additional include directories under Properties -> C++ and additional include libraries Properties -> Linker.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out yes!

Create environment variables LIB, INCLUDE and PATH

They match up with directory names.

I have included *all* in Additional Include directories, but only lib in Linker->Additional Include Libraries.

Woot!